# kendoEditor p tag

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the kendoEditor control and setting the insertLineBreak option but I would also like to remove the `<p>` tag that it is adding to the text. Is there a setting I can use like the insertLineBreak option?

```
var kendoEditor = $("#txtkendoEditor").data("kendoEditor");
if (!kendoEditor) {
    var defaultTools = kendo.ui.Editor.defaultTools;
    defaultTools["insertLineBreak"].options.shift = false;
    $("#txtkendoEditor").kendoEditor({
        encoded: false,
        tools: []
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delete the insertParagraph setting, however that will change it from inserting a `<p>` to inserting a `<br>` which may not be exactly what you want:

```
delete defaultTools["insertParagraph"].options;
```

Additional information here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/how-to/customize/change-p-to-br-tag